# Why ng-bind-html goes into infinite loop ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML:

```
<div tooltip="page 1 of 6, 2 of 11, 6 of 19" tooltip-placement="right"  ng-bind-html="getField('page_01','Subject','txt_sub_propAdd')"></div>
```

Angular :

```
$scope.currentField='';//Use to hendle Angular Deigest Loop
    $scope.getField = function(page, section, field) {
        console.log(i++,section,field);
        $scope.currentField=$sce.trustAsHtml(self.data.HTMLData[page][section][field]);
        return $scope.currentField;
};
```

Output at Console:

```
    0 "Subject" "txt_sub_propAdd"
    1 "Subject" "txt_sub_propAdd"
    2 "Subject" "txt_sub_propAdd"
    3 "Subject" "txt_sub_city"
    4 "Subject" "txt_sub_city"
    5 "Subject" "txt_sub_city"
    6 "Subject" "txt_sub_state"
    7 "Subject" "txt_sub_state"
-----
-----
-----
-----
till infinity
```

Output on Screen:

```
<div tooltip="page 1 of 6, 2 of 11, 6 of 19" tooltip-placement="right" ng-bind-html="getField('page_01','Subject','txt_sub_propAdd')" class="ng-binding"><input type="text" label="Property Address" name="txt_sub_propAdd" value=" " maxlength="60" minlength="30" required="" id=" " class="form-control" regex="[^A-Za-z0-9_-/]" ng-model="subject.txt_sub_propAdd"></div>
```

> PS: I've to show more that 600 fields on my screen(textboxes,radios,checkboxes). Also tell me know how can I get ng-model value in my controller.

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: `ng-bind` goes into infinite loop, because you pass function to it, that evaluate on every digest iteration, angular watch return value for this function, so you return `new` object on every function call, and watcher think that something change, and raise digest loop again :-)

Comment: you can also see [this docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig)

Comment: Instead of increasing maximum number of allowed iterations of the $digest  cycle can't we do a modification in my code.
May you please give a code snippet to come up with this problem.

Comment: just save result of `$sce.trustAsHtml` for all properties in array or object, and simple use this array instead function calling

Comment: if you can provide sample plunkr with sample data, i can be more concrete :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alright,
I'm saving result in array instead of calling function. Also I've used this directive to make my fields available for angular.

```
.directive('compile',function($compile, $timeout){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
            $timeout(function(){                
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);    
            });
        }        
    };
});
```